# Non Commutative rings which are not embeddable in matrix rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> Are there examples of non commutative rings which are not (which can not be) embedded in matrix rings?

Whatever example I know, all of them can be embedded in matrix ring. For example Quaternion ring, Group rings over a non-Abelian group.

Comment: Matrix ring over a commutative ring I assume? Do all your rings have a multiplicative identity? Do you allow matrices with an infinite number of entries?

Comment: Yes  I mean over commutative ring. Yes as I am following the approach of Artin , I assume my ring must have identity (as a definition ). I would prefer a example where infinite entries are not allowed. But anyways I would be happy to know such examples too.

Comment: "Affine PI-algebras Not Embeddable in Matrix Rings" Ronald S. Irving, Journal of Algebra 82, 94-101 (1983).  Have you access to this journal ?

Comment: yes , I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: A matrix ring $M_n(R)$ with $n>1$ apparently? Are you expecting $R$ to be a field or division ring, or anything else?

Comment: I would be happy to know such examples too.